# Does the Rdio Desktop API give tracks unique IDs?

Tags: python, api, applescript, sourceforge-appscript, rdio

I've built a small desktop app for myself that logs listens from iTunes and Rdio so I can create powerful playlists based on how I listen to music over time, but it requires each track to have a unique ID that will never change, regardless of which app I used to listen. I currently retrieve unique IDs from iTunes using appscript in Python:

```
from appscript import *
it = app('iTunes')
it.current_track.persistent_ID()
```

However, when poking through the Rdio Suite AppleScript Dictionary I don't see any kind of unique ID attached to tracks. Suggestions?

Comment: If Rdio does not provide a unique ID, even if it did it might be different that the one itunes provides, you can match song titles and that way get the id.

Comment: I'm not interested in the IDs between apps matching...

Answer (score 1):

Rdio has an [API](http://developer.rdio.com/). Here's some info on how to get the currently playing track: http://groups.google.com/group/rdio-api/browse_thread/thread/23d52c77b4e56a55/3b8a897f0835fd90

You can also get the url of the currently playing track via Applescript. This should serve as a sort of unique ID for the track:

```
osascript -e 'tell app "Rdio" to get the rdio url of the current track'
```

Answer (score 0):

All Rdio objects, including [`Tracks`](http://www.rdio.com/developers/docs/web-service/types/track/) have a `key` attribute that is the unique ID that can be used to look it up in Rdio using [`get`](http://www.rdio.com/developers/docs/web-service/methods/core/).